# How can I convert system millisecond to the Date in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting the date from web service like /Date(1326067200000)/ , how can I convert it to the date like DD.MM.YYYY?

Comment: Milliseconds since when? Year 0?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

```
    NSString *actDate = @"/Date(1326067200000)/";
    NSString *nDate = [[[[actDate componentsSeparatedByString:@"("] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@")"] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([nDate doubleValue] / 1000)];
```

In `date` you will get the actual date. Further you can format it in "MM/dd/yyyy" format by using

```
    NSDateFormatter *dtfrm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtfrm setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    nDate = [dtfrm stringFromDate:date];
```

In `nDate` you will get your desired date in a formatted way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSDate's initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate%3a) (assuming your value uses the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT as reference date) to get a NSDate instance representing your timestamp.

To get a formatted string representation, you can use the class [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
NSDate *date=[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gettingdate];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS"];
NSString *newdate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use of Function
textFiled.text = [self displayDate:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[AllKeys valueForKey:@"Date"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\"]]]]  


// Millisecond to Date conversion
- (NSDate *)displayDate:(double)unixMilliseconds {

    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixMilliseconds / 1000.];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSLog(@"The date is %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
  //  NSDate *returnValue = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return date;
}
```

Comment: `textField.text` is expecting a NSString,  but you are assigning a NSDate object. What is `AllKeys` and what does it have to do with `/Date(1326067200000)/`